# What is the distribution of edge lengths for a Euclidean minimal spanning tree?

Tags: spatial, graph-theory

Suppose that you have a Poisson point process in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with rate (density) parameter $\rho$; I particularly care about $d=2$ if there is a solution in this special case.  Given a finite realization, one can construct the minimal spanning tree of the ensemble.

I'd like to know (model/approximate) the distribution of the edge lengths, i.e.
if I select an edge from the tree at random, what is the distribution for it's length $l$?

I'm pretty sure by scaling arguments that $p_d(l \vert \rho)=f_d( \rho^{-1/d} l )$, but I don't have a good handle on how to get at the functional form.